# Why is an object not immutable if the "this" reference can escape during construction?

Tags: java, immutability

Section 3.4 of *Java Concurrency in Practice* says that an object is immutable if:

> 1. Its state cannot be modified after construction;
> 2. All its fields are final; and
> 3. It is *properly constructed* (the `this` reference does not escape during construction)

Why does allowing the `this` reference to escape during construction prevent an object from being immutable?

Note that I understand there are many problems associated with allowing the `this` reference to escape during construction. My particular question here is why it prevents an object from being considered *immutable*.

Comment: The question title asks why it stops a "class" from being immutable. Of course I mean an object.

Comment: improper construction means someone can see it in unfinished state, and again later in finished state. Immutable objects should only be observable in 1 state.

Comment: That seems like a good answer, but I can't accept it as a comment. I don't think this question has been asked before. Can you provide it as an answer?